# Find function in c++

Tags: c++

i am trying to find the ***char a or the char 1*** in a string. ***If they are not found***, my program will have a error message and exit. This is my function, however it does not seem to be working. Please help me out, thank you.

*update, if the string is a2, i will get the invalid message, it will only continue if the string is a1.

```
   bool hasAor1(const std::string& string)
   {
      return string.find_first_of("a1") != std::string::npos;
   }

   //find valid key, key must have numbers like 1234 instead of 134 
   void validstring(string key)
   {
      if(key.length() == 2)
      {
        hasAor1(key) == false;
        cerr << "invalid key";
      }      
   }
```

Comment: How about using the default c string function strstr? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Comment: @Jas First, this is tagged a `c++` not `c`. Second, using `"a1"` in that function wouldn't find `'a'` or `'1'` but rather `"a1"` exactly, see [here](http://ideone.com/LXib3N).

Comment: `hasAor1(key) == false;` - What do you think this is suppose to do?

Comment: @JamesAdkison To be fair c functions can be used in c++ programs with no issues.... but I won't mention c again whatever. Also, why did you make it " return ::strstr(string.c_str(), "a1") != nullptr;"? If you are looking for 'a' OR '1', it should be "strstr(string.c_str(), "a") != NULL || strstr(string.c_str(), "1") != NULL". Heres a similar link: http://ideone.com/CI6hGA

Comment: @Jas I only mention it because presumably the OP wants a `c++` solution (even though a `c` function could be used). Yes, I guess you could do that ... But now you're possibly doing a full search through the string twice instead of once. However, I'm no longer sure I even understand what the OP is asking.

Comment: relax guys @ James Adkison what you posted is what i wanted. However my program is still not getting the output you posted after i edit my code to become the example you posted.

Comment: @Bhappy - Please do not edit the question in this way - You fall into the trap that comments/answers stop making sense to the reader. Just make additions to the question.

Comment: @ Ed Heal, sorry i will take note. i Just saw your question on hasAor1(key) == false; It means if string(key) does not have a or 1 char

Comment: @Bhappy - This is not true. It calls `hasAor1(key)`, does a comparison with `false` and then throw away the result.

Comment: Wouldn't strcspn http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/ or strpbrk http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/ do the right thing without having to jump through hoops?

Answer (score 3):

[std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) would be much simpler to use here.

```
auto iter = find_if(begin(key), end(key),
        [](char v){ return v=='a' || v=='1'; });

if (iter == key.end()) cerr << "invalid key";
```

Comment: Why is using a longer and harder to read find_if much simpler than using the shorter find_first_of?

Answer (score 1):

The function hasAor1 is OK.

change the line with "hasAor1(key) == false;' to something like

if (!hasAor1(key)) cerr << "invalid key";

so

```
   //find valid key, key must have numbers like 1234 instead of 134 
   void validstring(string key)
   {
      if(key.length() == 2)
      {
        if (hasAor1(key) == false)
            cerr << "invalid key";
      }      
   }
```

It's not clear what validstring is supposed to do. What should it do if the key length is not 2? Shouldn't this be returning a bool or something? As it stands all it will do is print a message but only if the key length is 2. What do you want to happen if the key is "543" or "145" or "1a3"?

The comment in the code "//find valid key, key must have numbers like 1234 instead of 134" doesn't make sense because all of the examples of valid keys contain the character '1' which hasAor1 will mark as invalid.

You may want to think about the possible input variations and what you want to happen for each.

Comment: hello, i have solve it. I will update the answer when i have time. Thank you for your help. Im trying to improve other parts of my program. Have a nice day.